# Is it possible to derive $v>u$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given that $f>u$, is it possible to derive $v>u$ from $v={uf\over u+f}$? I got $v>{u\over 2}$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.  Let $u=2$ and $f=6$.  Then, $\frac{uf}{u+f}=\frac{12}{8}=\frac{3}{2}<2$.